# How to change sender name to display company name in ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: c#, .net, email, .net-core

I want to change the display name when sending otp through API. As for now the display is the email address, I want to change it to HORA . Have tried the solutions I got from here but its still not changing.

Here's the code

```
var emaillink = new MimeMessage();
emaillink.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("HORA","agus.mycareer@gmail.com"));
emaillink.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(email));
emaillink.Subject = "Email Verification Test " + (email);
emaillink.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html)
{
    Text = "https://localhost:7212/api/login" + verifyurl + " .the token will expire in 2 minutes"
};
using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Connect(_config.GetSection("EmailHost").Value, 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
smtp.Authenticate(_config.GetSection("EmailUsername").Value, _config.GetSection("EmailPassword").Value);
smtp.Send(emaillink);
smtp.Disconnect(true);
```

Comment: The built-in SMTP API in .NET is in the [System.Net.Mail](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.mail) namespace, which doesn't define `MimeMessage` or `MailboxAddress`. Assuming that this is a third-party API, you may want to edit your post to explain what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as below:

```
var emaillink = new MimeMessage();
emaillink.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("HORA <agus.mycareer@gmail.com>"));
emaillink.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(email));
emaillink.Subject = "Email Verification Test " + (email);
emaillink.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html)
{
    Text = "https://localhost:7212/api/login" + verifyurl + " .the token will expire in 2 minutes"
};
using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Connect(_config.GetSection("EmailHost").Value, 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
smtp.Authenticate(_config.GetSection("EmailUsername").Value, _config.GetSection("EmailPassword").Value);
smtp.Send(emaillink);
smtp.Disconnect(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `emaillink.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("HORA","agus.mycareer@gmail.com"));` try using below-

```
emaillink.From.Add(new MailboxAddress
{
    Name = "HORA",
    Address = "agus.mycareer@gmail.com"
});
```